# Combining two static libraries into one dynamic library whilst avoiding multiple definitions

Tags: c++, c, build, unix-ar

Note: This is not a duplicate question, because no other answer considers multiple definition challenges.

I am trying to combine two static libraries into one. (This works).

Then convert that static library into a dynamic library. (This does not work due to multiple definition error).

I have made a [public repo with example sources](https://github.com/wilderfield/combine_static_libs).

Here are the key components:

return_zero.cpp

```
int return_zero() { return 0; }
int version() { return 0; }
```

return_one.cpp

```
int return_one() { return 1; }
int version() { return 1; }
```

Note how each library has it's own `version` function.

I can build each of these into their own static libraries.
`libreturn_zero.a` and `libreturn_one.a`.

I can combine them into `libreturn.a` with the `ar` utility.

When I dump the symbols using `nm` utility:

```
$ nm -C libreturn.a 

return_one.cpp.o:
0000000000000000 T return_one()
000000000000000b T version()

return_zero.cpp.o:
0000000000000000 T return_zero()
000000000000000b T version()
```

Next, I try to convert this aggregate static library into a shared library.

I use a dummy source file, and link `libreturn.a` using the `--whole-archive` linker flag.

Here is what the link command looks like:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libreturn.so -o libreturn.so "dummy.cpp.o" -Wl,--push-state,--whole-archive libreturn.a -Wl,--pop-state
```

The above looks like what I want, but it fails because there are two definitions of version.

```
libreturn.a(return_zero.cpp.o): In function `version()':
return_zero.cpp:(.text+0xb): multiple definition of `version()'
libreturn.a(return_one.cpp.o):return_one.cpp:(.text+0xb): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/return-shared.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'libreturn.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libreturn.so] Error 1
```

I thought that by merging the two static libraries into one static library, the archiver would remove redundant symbols.

How do I go about merging static libraries into one shared library when there is a chance of symbol name conflicts?

Comment: "Note: This is not a duplicate question, because no other answer considers multiple definition challenges." - I'm pretty sure that is false.

Comment: You *built* a static library, but it does not *work*

Comment: A library is nothing but a collection of object files.

Comment: Which instance of  `version()` are you expecting to call when you link to the final *shared library*?

Comment: The [tag:unix-ar] tag has a number of questions about the `ar` command and linking libraries, and a number of questions about combining libraries are shown as duplicates on the first page of output.  (For a long time, the tag was just [tag:ar] but the augmented-reality people eventually got their way and the [tag:ar] was granted to them — probably about the same time that it stopped being as compelling a question area as it had been.)

Comment: @Galik I see your point. I don't really want this version function to be called at all by the end application. I want it to remain an internal method to the original library. However, I guess the approach I'm taking can't achieve this.

Comment: @CraigDavid Then you could mark the function as `static` as in `static int version()`. That means only functions in the same translation unit (and therefore library) can call it. It will not be visible to the external linker.

Comment: Odd. I would have thought `ar` would be reserved for questions about piracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the aggregate static library if you have code that calls both `return_one()` and `return_zero()` because you will get duplicate symbol problems with the `version()` functions.

How will you decide which `version()` function you want to call if you link with the aggregate library?

You're going to have to resolve that issue — and that probably means something like prefixing all the functions from `return_zero.cpp` with a prefix such as `r0_` (or, in C++, placing them in `namespace return_zero { … }`), and — for symmetry, if for no better reason — prefixing all the functions from `return_one.cpp` with a prefix such as `r1_`  (or placing them in `namespace return_one { … }`).  Your calling code would then use the prefixed names (or prefix the functions with the appropriate namespace name).